# Error trying to install gazebo_worlds

Tags: ros, gazebo, eigen, rosdep, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to install gazebo on Fedora 15 following the instructions here:

[Starting Gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo)

I've followed all the beginner tutorials and ROS worked fine, so I assume it's correctly installed.

When I try to install gazebo I get the following error:

```
[manu@manu simulator_gazebo]$ rosdep install gazebo_worlds
Failed to find rosdep eigen for package gazebo_worlds on OS:fedora version:15
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install eigen
```

I couldn't find an answer related to this... does somebody know how to solve this dependency?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31885/error-trying-to-install-gazebo_worlds/) by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep rules for eigen are missing.  See the [rosdep tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep/Tutorials/Add%20new%20OS%20to%20rosdep.yaml) for adding one.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) on 2012-04-20**:
Many Thanks tfoote!
I added this lines to the rosdep.yaml file:
eigen:
fedora: eigen3-devel
And now the eigen package was successfully installed :)